# String in set gives weird results

Tags: python, set, comparison, string-comparison

My code is reading the header of a csv file and converting that to a lookup table of column_name=>column_index:

```
class CSVOutput:
  def __init__(self, csv_file, required_columns):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    # Construct lookup table for header
    self.header = {}
    for idx, column in enumerate(next(csv_reader)):
      print(f"{column.lower().strip()} == key: {column.lower().strip() == 'key'}")
      print(f"{column.lower().strip()} is key: {column.lower().strip() is 'key'}")
      self.header[column.lower().strip()] = idx

    print(self.header)

     # Load the row data into memory/index it against key
     key_idx = self.header['key']

with open("test.csv") as csv_file:
    data = CSVOutput(csv_file, {})
```

When I run this, I get the following output and error:

```
{'key': 0, 'col1': 1, 'col2': 2}

key == key: False
key is key: False
col1 == key: False
col1 is key: False
col2 == key: False
col2 is key: False

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\compare.py", line 74, in <module>
    actual_data = CSVOutput(act_csv, required_columns)
  File "D:\compare.py", line 40, in __init__
    key_idx = self.header['key']
KeyError: 'key'
```

Basically there seems to be an inequivalence between the literal 'key' and the 'key' that's loaded from the file.  I've tried looking at the source file in notepad++ with show all symbols on, but I'm not seeing any difference.  I've also just had a look at the csv file in a hex editor and I can see the start looks like this: ï»¿Key, ï»¿ being EF BB BF.  I'm not sure if that's the source of my problem, but if it is, why isn't strip() getting rid of it, and how do I handle that?

Any ideas?

Comment: is self.header inside a class function?

Comment: yes sorry should have added context.  This is inside the constructor of CSVOutput

Comment: could you add that part of the  code so we get some context

Comment: Added, note the required_columns aren't used in the provided code as I simplified it here

Comment: could you also put the first few lines of your csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EF BB BF

This is [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), you might use [`utf-8-sig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) encoding to deal with such files. Use `encoding` of [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function following way

```
with open("test.csv",encoding="utf-8-sig") as csv_file:
```

Comment: How do I do that?  I've just updated the code to show how I'm loading the file.

If it helps to explain, the file originally came from a process I ran in linux, I'm running this script in windows after retrieving the file via ftp.

Comment: @Andy I update my question